# Sort list by names stored in vector

Tags: r

I have a named list:

**The_list**

```
$df1

    col1  col2
1   M     P
2   N     Q
3   O     R

$df2

    col1  col2
1   G     J
2   H     K
3   I     L

$df3

    col1  col2
1   A     D
2   B     E
3   C     F
```

How could I do a custom (i.e. not alphabetical) sort of the list by names that is stored in a vector:

```
order <- c("df2", "df3", "df1")
```

and then get :

**The_list**

```
$df2

    col1  col2
1   G     J
2   H     K
3   I     L

$df3

    col1  col2
1   A     D
2   B     E
3   C     F


$df1

    col1  col2
1   M     P
2   N     Q
3   O     R
```

So far I tried:

```
The_list[order(c("df2", "df3", "df1"))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The_list[c("df2","df3","df1")]
```